# How to get multidimensional array data using java script and php

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a multidimensional array in php, and i want to get its data from javascript but i didn't work

here my code in php

```
$managername = $_SESSION['managername'];

              $sqls = "select s.*,m.* from rm_allowedmanagers m inner join rm_services s on s.srvid = m.srvid where m.managername = '$managername' ";


                $sql = mysql_query($sqls);

                $newservices =  array();

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                  {
                        $nsrvid = $row['srvid'];
                        $nsrvname = $row['srvname'];                        
                        $nunitprice = $row['unitprice'];
                        $nunitpricetax = $row['unitpricetax'];

                        $ntotal = $nunitprice + $nunitpricetax;

                        $newservice = array($nsrvid, $nsrvname , $ntotal); 

                        array_push ($newservices, $newservice);

               }
```

and here my java script code

```
                <script>

                function changeserviceprice(id)
                    {
                        var newservice = $("#newservice").val();

                        var data = '<?= $newservices ?>';

                        var asd = data;

                        var asd2 = data[0][0];

                        $("#qq4").val(asd);
                        $("#qq5").val(asd2);

                    }                   

                </script>
```

PHP code i think it is work fine, and i think the error is in javascript function.

when i try to print the data using javascript it print the "Array" word when i print the whole row "array", but
it print "a" character when i try to print the first element in the first array!!

Answer (score 0):

try encoding the $newservices array:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($newservices); ?>;
```